# iReport : insert detail band into height fixed frame

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to display a list in a report.
I need this list to be displayed in a 4cm height frame. If the list is bigger than 4cm, it has to be truncated at 4cm.

I don't know how to do that, how to include a detail band into a height fixed frame.

Comment: Do you need the height in pixel fixed or is maximum number of elements (rows) displayed enough?

Comment: both are good for me

Comment: Ok I have answers how you do it with maximum number of elements in detail band.... that surely is the best (and the way that jasper report was developed)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"how to include a detail band into a height fixed frame?, truncated at 4cm."*

The **main strength** of jasper report is to expand bands to include all the  content you provide..

This is why I suggest that you re-think your report, not trying to truncate content but providing less content. The fastest one would be **limit** the rows displayed in your detail band. es.

```
<detail>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}<=4)]]></printWhenExpression>
        .... your textField's ...
    </band>
</detail>
```

even if my datasource provide 100 records I will only print the 4 first one's.

No ugly truncation, instead we handle this case with some logic and one day we can even transform the 4 into a parameter (and as example the user can define how many records he like) or a variable that on the basis of other content defines the number of rows we like to display...

**EDIT**: Added how to achieve this result with the `jr:list` component (no  detail band)

If you are using a `jr:list` component (you have no detail band), you need to set the `printWhenExpression` and `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` on the components that are inside the `jr:list` es.

```
<jr:listContents height="20" width="100">
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c65e627e-be7f-4bce-9976-f89c5ccc5d68">
    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}<=4)]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{theField}]]></textFieldExpression>
  </textField>
</jr:listContents>
```

**NOTE**: `new Boolean()` is used to be compatible with jasper report v3 (with version 5/6 this is not needed)